# Expand animation with Angular inside mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm a student and I'm making a graduation project. I have some problem in animation of Angular. I will explain below...
First of all, this is my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmn4cd), please give it a visit.
I want this only show when selected role is Student. See the image below 
[image: First]
And It will hide when role is un-selected or not equal student. See the image below. But, while not displaying, seem it's height (or element which is in side) still there, cause a scroll bar and a "blank" zone
[image]

I tried to style it to display:none,

```
state(
    "out",
    style({
        "max-height": "0px",
        "opacity": "0",
        "visibility": "hidden",
        "display": "none"
    })
),
```

but when I do it, the expading animation will gone.
Can you point me what wrong I made there?

Note: I only meet this problem when put `<form>` inside mat-tab. When I leave it alone, the code work fine. This is [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmn4cd-vxe6dx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, by adding this css in to my `<form>` tag

```css
.custom {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```